# Managed Package: Detect from post install script if it's patch or major version

Tags: apex, managed-package, postinstall, patch

When our managed package is installed in subscriber org, we need to populate some custom settings from post install script. But different data should be inserted for major version versus patch version of our package.

So the question here is - how to detect from apex code in post install script whether major or patch version has just been installed to populate appropriate data?

My initial attempt was to go with System.requestVersion().patch() - but no way, it always returns null and that's mentioned explicitly in Apex Dev Guide. So this is not an option(